# How to fix a flashing roof leak?

Tags: repair, leak, roof, flashing

I have a roof leak. Based on the images below I think it is in the flashing above a small overhang. Please speak up if you don't think that's correct.

Can anyone provide some guidance on what to look for in order to verify the source of the leak, how to fix it, and how to ensure the fix was successful?

**Images**

The image below shows a wet ceiling. Water was dripping from behind the window trim where I'm pointing. 
[image: Wet Ceiling and Dripping Water]

The image below shows the window interior.
[image: Window Interior]

The image below shows the window exterior. Based on this image I believe there is flashing right above the leak. 
[image: Window Exterior]

The image below shows a closeup on the corner of the overhang above the leak
[image: Corner of Overhang]

Comment: I'd like to see better pics of the roof area, the flashing area, etc.  Do you have a ladder you can get up on ?

Comment: Also it looks to me at a glance that the slope on that little mini-roof is inappropriate for shingles.

Comment: Slope is fine. 2:12 is usually minimum, and that looks like 4:12.  We need to see the flashing situation at that outside corner. There doesn't appear to be a kicker of any sort, so water's running right behind the siding. Show us a view from straight on looking over the right edge of the roof.

Comment: Maybe 2-in-12 is allowable for composition shingles for a precisely flat roof section, but we have 26 squares of 3-in-12 and we have had trouble with leaks with composition shingles.  Some places the roof decking was slightly uneven and allowed backflow into the high side..

Comment: A water barrier would've been prudent. That's a different issue. Ice dams can cause backup on any slope.

Comment: I’ll bet it’s leaking in the wall above that is 90 degrees to the window, because 1) no step flashing under last row of shingles, 2) no paper extending out from under last row of wall shingles, 3) corner of upper wall aligns perfectly with stain on ceiling, 4) awkward corner where everything comes together adjacent to stain. You’ll need to take the entire corner apart, including the wall siding, etc. to see what is happening.

Comment: I meant to get better pictures last night but didn't have time before sunset. So I added a closeup of the overhang. I'm not an expert, but it seems like the trim piece inside the yellow box would catch runoff from the siding above and dump it out right above where the leak is. Is that an inappropriate use of a trim piece?